# Changing a spinner list based on the position of a different spinner

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, spinner, adapter

In my project I have a spinner to select unit type (Length, Mass, etc.) and then two spinners that I want to change depending on what the user selects. So if the user chooses Mass as their unit from the first spinner the second and third spinner should change the lists they display showing grams, pounds, etc.

I am trying to use the onItemSelectedListener() of conversionAdapter in order to switch the lists being displayed by the other two spinners. None of my attempts have worked because this inner class cannot access the spinners in the main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView equalSign;
private Spinner conversionSpinner, unitOneSpinner, unitTwoSpinner;
private EditText unitOneEditText, unitTwoEditText;
private List selectedList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    equalSign = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.equal_sign);
    equalSign.setImageResource(R.drawable.equal_sign_black_2);

    unitOneEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.unit_one);
    unitTwoEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.unit_two);

    conversionSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.conversion_spinner);

    String[] conversion_list = {"Length", "Mass", "Time", "Temperature", "Volume"};
    String[] length_list = {"Kilometer", "Meter", "Centimeter", "Millimeter", "Micrometer", "Nanometer", "Mile", "Yard", "Inch"};
    String[] mass_list = {"Metric Ton", "Kilogram", "Gram", "Milligram", "Microgram", "Pound", "Ounce"};
    String[] time_list = {"Nanosecond", "Microsecond", "Millisecond", "Second", "Minute", "Hour", "Day", "Year", "Decade", "Century"};
    String[] temp_list = {"Fahrenheit", "Celsius", "Kelvin"};
    String[] volume_list = {"US Liquid Gallon", "US Liquid Quart", "US Liquid Pint", "US Legal Cup", "US Fluid Ounce", "US Tablespoon", "US Teaspoon", "Liter", "Milliliter"};

    List<String>conversion_types = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String>length = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String>mass = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String>time = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String>temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String>volume = new ArrayList<String>();

    conversion_types = updateList(conversion_types, conversion_list);
    length = updateList(length, length_list);
    mass = updateList(mass, mass_list);
    time = updateList(time, time_list);
    temp = updateList(temp, temp_list);
    volume = updateList(volume, volume_list);

    selectedList = length;

    ArrayAdapter<String> conversionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, conversion_types);
    conversionSpinner.setAdapter(conversionAdapter);
    conversionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String unitType = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            switch(unitType){
                case "length":
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Length", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "Mass":
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "Time":
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "Temperature":
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Temperature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "Volume":
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    unitOneSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.unit_one_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> unitOneAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, selectedList);
    unitOneSpinner.setAdapter(unitOneAdapter);
    unitOneSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    unitTwoSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.unit_two_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> unitTwoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, selectedList);
    unitTwoSpinner.setAdapter(unitTwoAdapter);
    unitTwoSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    unitOneAdapter.clear();
    unitOneAdapter = updateList(unitOneAdapter, mass_list);
    unitOneAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public List<String> updateList(List<String> myArray, String[] list){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        myArray.add(list[i]);
    }
    return myArray;
}

//Overloaded method used for ArrayAdapters
public ArrayAdapter<String> updateList(ArrayAdapter<String> myArray, String[] list){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        myArray.add(list[i]);
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue, you are facing?

Comment: I have 3 spinners. The main spinner lets the user choose a unit type (Length, Mass, Time, etc.). When the user selects one of these options I would like the second and third spinner to display a list that reflects the units of the first spinner. Ex. the user chooses Time for the first spinner, the second spinners will have their lists updated to show seconds, minutes, hours, rather than inches or pounds. The main issue is that I cannot reach the other spinners from the onItemSelectedListener of the first spinner.

Comment: Define you adapters as fields of Activity or create a new adapter with new data and set to spinner

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: @Flint like you defined the Views.

Comment: When I try to define a new adapter I get an error. ArrayAdapter<String>testAdapterOne = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, selectedList); Gives me an error when defining the layout for some reason.